# Regex to Extract Report ID Out of a multi-dimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, regex, multidimensional-array

Here's my problem.  We got some sample PHP that didn't work so I've been trying to write this more or less "by the seat of my pants".  My regex is rusty and I've not dealt with multidimensional arrays, so this is outside my realm of experience.

I'm getting an array like this one but I only want the report ID's where [1] contains the word "Export" and then I need to pass those to another script where I have to do more or less the same thing to get a result set ID that I can pass to another script that I can actually export.

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => REPORTIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [1] => REPORT EXPORT NAME#1
        [2] => REPORT DESCRIPTION #1
        [3] => 2012-10-02T17:31:30
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => REPORTIDYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
        [1] => REPORTOTHERNAME#2
        [2] => REPORTDESCRIPTION #2
        [3] => 2012-09-28T15:15:17
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => REPORTIDZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
        [1] => REPORT EXPORT NAME#3
        [2] => REPORT DESCRIPTION #3
        [3] => 2012-09-28T14:59:17
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function get_report_ids(array $rs) {
   $results = array();
   // loop over your data structure
   foreach($rs as $key => $data) {

      // If element 1 contains EXPORT (case insensitive)
      if(stripos($data[1], 'EXPORT') !== false) {
         // regex to capture the ID from element 0
         if(preg_match('/^EXPORTID(.*)$/i', $data[0], $matches)) {
            // add the ID to the results array
            $results[] = $matches[1];
         }
      }
   }

   // if we had results then return the array, otherwise return null
   return !empty($results) ? $results : null;
}
```

Example return value:

```
array(
  0 => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  1 => 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
)
```